# keep the mouse position in GrapeCity Spread

Tags: c#, componentone

I'm using a tool GrapeCity, the spread 6. NET (C #) and I'm giving it to bind every 5 seconds, but every postback the page returns to the point that the mouse was before the postback.
as the postback takes to complete, the User has the possibility to continue browsing while processing does not end and ends when the mouse pointer back to start position.
any suggestions?